# Inizialize Object in shared library on c++

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-libraries

can I inizialize one object like :

```
extern Test test = Test();
```

from one shared library and use the test object into the principal binary?

Comment: How is `test` defined (not only declared) in the main program??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in terms of the larger context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extern Test test ;
```

refers to an object allocated and initialized somewhere else.  You cannot initialize it there.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your context (extern is a keyword for a C and is miss-used here, it does not define a variable, only links to one and so can not be initialized) but since it is an object you need **new**

Test *test = new Test();

Comment: Can't work, unless you mean `Test *test=new Test;` because `test` should then be a *pointer*, not an *object*.

Comment: Thanks! I've overseen that was to focused on the forgotten new

Comment: But then you don't answer the original's poster question.